# grails plugin repositories

Tags: grails, groovy

By default, the following repositories are configured in `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
repositories {
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()    // look inside the grails installation
    grailsCentral()
}
```

I understand that the `grailsHome()` repository corresponds to the JARs that are available within the local Grails installation, and I guess `grailsPlugins()` corresponds to the repository where [released Grails plugins are stored](http://grails.org/plugin/category/all).

Am I right about these two, and if so, what is `grailsCentral()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand it;

`grailsPlugins()` [looks inside](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-bootstrap/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/resolve/IvyDependencyManager.groovy#L892) the `~/.grails/version` directory

`grailsHome()` (as you suspected) looks [inside the Grails installation directory](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-bootstrap/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/resolve/IvyDependencyManager.groovy#L902)

`grailsCentral()` looks to be using the [grails subversion repository](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-bootstrap/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/resolve/IvyDependencyManager.groovy#L1021)

Comment: The path you suggested for grailsPlugins() is wrong, look at my answer for the right location it points to.

Comment: @sudhir Yeah things have probably changed over the 3 years

Answer (score 3):

Here's exactly where it is looks for

- `grailsPlugins()` - Looks for jars inside /lib directory of each installed plugin. 
  (See GrailsPluginsDirectoryResolver)
- `grailsHome()` - Looks inside the GRAILS-HOME/lib directory
- `grailsCentral()` - Looks at http://grails.org/plugins